# Unterscheidung zwischen "auch" als Modalpartikel und als logische Verknüpfung

Tags: sentence-structure, modal-particle

Modalpartikeln wie *denn, ja, wohl, schon, aber, allerdings, eigentlich, natürlich, auch* etc. (auch Rede-, Abtönungs- oder Einstellungspartikel genannt) haben im entsprechenden Kontext im Deutschen Appellfunktion, d. h., sie tragen nichts zur Sachinformation bei, sondern richten sich direkt an den Adressaten, in der Regel, um einen Konsens anzuregen oder aufrechtzuerhalten. Man kann sie also **weglassen, ohne die Aussage zu verändern**.

Die Konjunktion "auch" hat jedoch primär eine logische Funktion, indem sie eine Aussage erweitert und den Zusatz in bestimmter Weise hervorhebt. Doch manchmal ist es schwer oder gar nicht zu erkennen, welche dieser Funktionen dem "auch" zugedacht ist:

> Wissenschaftliche Autoren sollten sich fragen, wieweit sie mit ihrer
>   Satzstruktur den Informationsfluss des Textes verbessern können. Der
>   Krimiautor fragt sich hingegen, mit welcher Satzstruktur er seinem
>   Publikum Information vorenthalten kann, um die Spannung zu erhöhen,
>   doch er verwendet auch andere Mittel dazu.

Es wird meiner Meinung nicht klar, ob man das "auch" weglassen darf oder nicht. Tatsächlich hat es jedoch hier logische Funktion und drückt aus, dass der Krimiautor auch noch andere Möglichkeiten hat, Spannung zu erzeugen, als durch die Gestaltung der Satzstruktur. Meine Frage:

> Ist es in diesem Beispiel überhaupt nötig, und auf welche Weise kann
>   für das "auch" allgemein klar gemacht werden, dass es Aussage- und
>   nicht bloß moderierende Funktion hat?

Comment: Du kannst versuchen, es in eine Sprache zu übersetzen, die ebenfalls ein logisches "auch" hat, aber kein Partikel-auch. Wenn eine Übersetzung funktioniert, dann ist das ein klares Zeichen dafür, dass es sich nicht um die Partikel handelt. In dem Beispiel finde ich es übrigens relativ eindeutig, bzw. ich sehe das Problem nicht.

Comment: Habe die abschließende Frage bearbeitet, um deutlich zu machen, dass sie auch allgemein mit Hinsicht auf das Verhältnis zwischen Modal- und Aussagefunktion gemeint war und nicht allein auf das Beispiel bezogen.

Comment: Die Antwort von @Em1 hat mich zu einer Nachfrage gebracht. In folgendem Satz: "Ich habe jedenfalls die Küche gekauft.", ist das "jedenfalls" für dich ein(e) Modalpartikel?

Comment: Ja, es hat für mich hier moderierende Funktion wie z.B. "wie auch immer", "der langen Rede kurzer Sinn" etc.

Comment: Eine kleine Anmerkung: Im sprachwissenschaftlichen Kontext heißt es Sg. *die Partikel*, Pl. *die Partikeln*. (Wusste ich auch lange Zeit nicht.)

Comment: Allerdings lässt sich "jedenfalls" in dem Satz verschieben. Ein klares Zeichen, dass es keine Partikel ist. Ich habe deshalb gefragt, weil es viele Satzadverbien gibt, die in erster Linie Kommentarfunktion haben. Wie z.B. "leider", oder "wenigstens" in "Wenigstens habe ich ein Bier." Das sind jedoch noch keine Modalpartikeln im Sinne von "doch" oder "halt", da sie a) grammatisch anderes Verhalten zeigen und b) durch Synonyme ersetzbar/umschreibbar sind. In diese Kategorie scheint mir "auch" auch zu fallen.. ctd

Comment: Die einzige wirkliche modale Verwendung (im Sinne einer Partikel), die mir einfällt, ist: "Was er auch tut..." wobei das vielleicht auch eher als fixe Wendung betrachtet werden muss, da es keinen Dialog braucht um zu funktionieren.

Comment: @Chris Vielen Dank für den Hinweis, es liegt wohl daran, dass mir das Wort in der Literatur bewusst immer nur im Plural begegnet ist. Es stammt von lat. particula, -ae, daher ist Partikel weiblich.

Answer (score 6):

Für mich ist dieses Beispiel absolut eindeutig.

A) Original:

> Wissenschaftliche Autoren sollten sich fragen, wieweit sie mit ihrer Satzstruktur den Informationsfluss des Textes verbessern können. Der Krimiautor fragt sich hingegen, mit welcher Satzstruktur er seinem Publikum Information vorenthalten kann, um die Spannung zu erhöhen, doch er verwendet auch andere Mittel dazu.

-> das "auch" muss hier im Sinne von "zusätzlich" gelesen werden und ist damit eindeutig notwendig.

B) Als Versuch/Gegenbeweis ohne "auch":

> Wissenschaftliche Autoren sollten sich fragen, wieweit sie mit ihrer Satzstruktur den Informationsfluss des Textes verbessern können. Der Krimiautor fragt sich hingegen, mit welcher Satzstruktur er seinem Publikum Information vorenthalten kann, um die Spannung zu erhöhen, doch er verwendet andere Mittel dazu.

In Betrachtung des zweiten Satzes **alleine** könnte man bei schnellem Querlesen argumentieren, das "auch" fehle nicht. 
Aber wie im vorausgehenden Satz wird die Satzstruktur als Mittel zum Informationsfluss diskutiert-> Spätestens unter Berücksichtigung des ersten Satzes ("Wissenschaftliche Autoren...") entsteht ein logischer Widerspruch. Zumindest schließt je nach Lesart der zweite Satz den Gebrauch der Satzstruktur zur Informationsunterdrückung aus, was die Originalaussage ins Gegenteil verkehrt.=> das "auch" darf nicht entfallen -> keine Modalpartikel.

Answer (score 2):

Das *auch* ist hier elementar und kann nicht weggelassen werden. Die Bedeutung des Satzes verändert sich wesentlich, wenn das *auch* weggelassen wird.

> …, doch er verwendet auch andere Mittel dazu. -> zusätzlich
>   …, doch er verwendet andere Mittel dazu. -> stattdessen

Ich kann ehrlich gesagt auch nicht nachvollziehen, wo das Problem ist. Du hast ja selbst schon gesagt, dass *auch* hier eine Kernfunktion hat. Daher kann man es einzig durch ein Synonym ersetzen ("…, doch er verwendet zusätzlich noch andere Mittel dazu."), jedoch darf man es unter keinen Umständen auslassen.

Interessanterweise habe ich aber gerade einen Satz geschrieben, in dem das *auch* zweideutig ist:

> Ich kann ehrlich gesagt auch nicht nachvollziehen ...

Man muss letzten Endes einen jeden solchen Satz individuell betrachten, um sagen zu können, wie der Satz eindeutig formuliert werden könnte, sprich, auf welche Art und Weise das *auch* eindeutig wird.
In diesem konkreten Beispiel hat *auch* folgende mögliche Bedeutungen:

1. Ich kann einfach nicht nachvollziehen …
2. Ich kann ebenfalls nicht nachvollziehen …

Ich hätte hier der Eindeutigkeit halber *ebenfalls* anstatt von *auch* verwenden sollen. Ich sehe keine Möglichkeit, den Satz eindeutig zu gestalten, wenn ich *auch* gebrauche.
Aber auch hier hätte ich es nicht weglassen können, weil es eine entscheide Funktion hat. Hätte ich es im Sinne von (1) gemeint, dann wäre es wiederum möglich gewesen, das Wörtchen einfach unter den Teppich zu kehren: "Ich kann ehrlich gesagt nicht nachvollziehen, …."

Comment: Ich glaube, niemand würde "Ich kann auch nicht nachvollziehen" als "einfach" interpretieren. Diese Bedeutun von "auch" wäre mir auch neu. Das "auch" bezieht in diesem Fall einfach das folgende auf das bisher gesagte. Es drückt soviel wie "zusätzlich will ich sagen". Ein Beispiel für "auch" als Partikel wäre "Was er auch versuchte, er konnte es nicht schaffen."

Comment: Es hat wohl auch damit zu tun, wie man sich einen geschriebenen Satz selber vorliest. In "er verwendet auch andere Mittel dazu" kann man "andere Mittel" betonen - Modalpartikel - oder "auch" - Aussagefunktion. Stephie hat mit der Kontextlogik argumentiert - was ich sehr sinnvoll finde, aber man kann das sicherlich durch Wortwahl und Satzbau unterstützen oder erschweren.

Comment: @Emanuel Ich wollte "auch" und "einfach" hier nicht gleichstellen und sagen, dass "auch" = "einfach" bedeutet. Lese ich den Satz aber ohne "auch", so verstehe ich den Satz recht abwertend. Und genau das würde durch "einfach" noch verstärkt. Daher, wenn man "auch" nicht als "ebenfalls" interpretiert, so liegt es nahe, den Satz abwertend zu verstehen, so nach dem Motto: Es ist mir unbegreiflich, wie man dieser Auffassung sein kann. – Oder mit "auch": Wie kann man auch nur dieser Auffassung sein.